# `parse_response': undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby

I want to implement method which raises errors based on status code. I tried to implement this code:

```
def parse_response

    system_errors = { }

    (100..199).each do |current|
      system_errors[current.to_s] = SystemError
    end

    (200..999).each do |current|
      system_errors[current.to_s] = CommunicationError
    end

    return params_for_success if successful_response?

    # pp system_errors
    pp payment_response
    if valid?
      raise system_errors[340].new(technical_message, response_code)
    else
      raise errors.full_messages.join(";\n")
    end
  end

  def successful_response?
    response_code == RESPONSE_CODE_FOR_SUCCESS
  end

  def params_for_success
    payment_response.dig(:payment_response)
  end

.....

class CommunicationError < StandardError
  def initialize(current_technical_message, response_code)
    @response = response
  end
end
```

But I get error `parse_response': undefined method`new' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)`

What is the proper way to raise error based on a range of numbers?
This line is causing the issue: `system_errors[:error_class].new(technical_message, response_code)`

Comment: "raise system_errors[:error_class].new" - what kind of keys do you think `system_errors` contains? Does it contain `:error_class`?

Comment: I just saw it. I will update my answer.

Comment: Same question, do you think it contains `:response_code`? What is the difference between `:response_code` and `response_code`?

Comment: I updated the post.

Comment: Do you think `340` will be equal to `"340"`? This is not javascript :)

Comment: no - this s the mistake.

Comment: Yep, that it is. And also two others that we found above :)

Answer (score 0):

Unlike Javascript, Ruby does not implicitly convert between types.

```
(200..999).each do |current|
  system_errors[current.to_s] = CommunicationError
end
# now we have
system_errors["340"] == CommunicationError
```

So later when you do

```
raise system_errors[340].new(technical_message, response_code)
```

It uses the *interger* key `340` rather than the *string* key `"340"`. Missing keys return `nil`, so you're calling `nil.new`. Decide on whether you're going to use integer or string keys and stick to it when inserting/reading.